# image not staying set after page reload PHP

Tags: php, html, session, cookies, session-cookies

I have a function on a site that I'm working on where you can change the background image and there is PHP script that should make sure that the image that you choose stays even after a reload, but at the moment it's not working and the image is cleared after a reload, here is a sample of my index that has the php;

```
 <body>
  <?php       
    session_start();
    if(isset ($_SESSION['images']))
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">changeImage('.$_SESSION['images'].')</sript>';  
    }
  ?>
  <div id="chooseBg" style="width:200px;text-align:center;">
   <a href="#" onclick="changeImage(1);"><img src="images/1.jpg"/></a>
```

and here is the PHP script that's running;

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['number']))
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['image'] = $_POST['number'];
}
if(isset($_GET['resetBg']))
{
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
}
?>
```

I think it's an issue with cookies, the first time that you go to the site it will allow you to chose a background, and will create a cookie, the next time that you load the site it will be empty, and only deleting the cookie will show the site again.

Here is a link to the site that I am working on;

http://playground.eca.ed.ac.uk/~s1572393/setting/index.php#

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Put session_start before any output (including <body>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is an error in your html 
you haven't closed the script properly ( )
Also the function call should be after the html instance.

```
<body>   
<?php       
    session_start();
     ?>   
<div id="chooseBg" style="width:200px;text-align:center;">    
<a href="#" onclick="changeImage(1);">
<img src="images/1.jpg"/></a>'



<?php   if(isset ($_SESSION['images']))
        {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">changeImage('.$_SESSION['images'].')</script>';

        }

    ?>
```

Comment: Use console / script inspector tools on chrome/firefox to track the javascript errors if any

Comment: Thanks for the answer it's solved the issue, the image will remain after I reload now, there were some errors in the console previously but I had cleared them, partly why I wasn't sure what the issue was, thank you again.